# Sublime Text to display R native pipe |> ligature with Fira Code

Tags: r, pipe, sublimetext4, fira-code

I am using R in Sublime Text with [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode), and would like to display the new native Pipe `|>` as a triangle ligature.

This works well with most syntaxes, but not in the R syntax, where it actually matters:

[image]

[image]

Any idea what I could do?

Comment: Are you using the builtin R syntax, or a plugin's, such as R-Box or R-IDE?

Comment: I am using the built-in syntax.

Comment: In that case this is an issue with the R syntax definition; symbols are passed for rendering based on how the syntax groups them together when it's matching, so the rules it's currently using are not grouping the characters together.  To fix it open an issue in the tracker. Note however that ST3 is no longer going to receive updates and the syntax engine in ST4 is enhanced so if the problem is resolved there's a high liklyhood that it won't work in ST3.

Comment: Thanks! I am using ST4, and don't care about ST3. I opened an issue as suggested: https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/issues/3119

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this also came up yesterday on Twitter in this [tweet](https://twitter.com/christoph_sax/status/1455890036608602131) with the follow-up a few hours later [in this tweet](https://twitter.com/christoph_sax/status/1455947962895552517) pointing to a pending PR and this compelling picture:

[image]

which I am just posting to bring closure here.

Signed, someone who locally compiled Emacs a while back to get a newer version for ligatures onto his workstation / into his distro :)  Loving it too.